# Is the series expansion of $\frac1{(1+x)^n}$ same as $\frac1{(1-x)^n}$ with $(-1)^r$

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion, binomial-theorem

The series expansion for $$\frac1{(1-x)^n}  =
\sum_{r=0}^{r=\infty}C_r^{|n|+r-1}x^r$$
Is the expansion of $$\frac1{(1+x)^n} = \sum_{r=0}^{r=\infty}(-1)^rC_r^{|n|+r-1}x^r$$ ?? (Where C is combination)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have the correct expansions with the exception of the absolute values on $n$.  To see why we use the [generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem):
$$
(x+y)^s=\sum _{r=0}^{\infty }{s \choose r}x^{s-r}y^r,
$$
which requires $|x|>|y|$ to converge if $s\notin\Bbb N_0$. Substituting $x=1$ and $s=-n$ one has
$$
\frac{1}{(1+y)^n}=\sum _{r=0}^\infty {-n \choose r}y^r,
$$
which converges for $|y|<1$. Now note
$$
{-n \choose r}=(-1)^r\frac{(n)_r}{r!}=(-1)^r\frac{(n-1+r)!}{(n-1)!r!}=(-1)^r{n+r-1 \choose r},
$$
so that
$$
\frac{1}{(1+y)^n}=\sum _{r=0}^\infty {n+r-1 \choose r}(-y)^r.
$$
Finally substitute $y\mapsto -x$ and $y\mapsto x$ to get
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^n}=\sum _{r=0}^\infty {n+r-1 \choose r}x^r
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{(1+x)^n}=\sum _{r=0}^\infty (-1)^r{n+r-1 \choose r}x^r.
$$